# JS: for loop with pauses

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

How can I make a loop pause when a certain condition is satisfied? In the example below loop just shows all values at once while I want it to stop any time it gets across specific value (e.g. 2):

```
a = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,1]
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] == 2){
        setTimeout(console.log(a[i]), 1000)
    }else{
        console.log(a[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: javascript has no `pause` functionality, you would need to refactor your code to use like setTimeout and setup variables to flag when to pause and when to continue etc.

Comment: In the refactoring you will probably want to scope `i` above the _function_ so that it will be shared across multiple invocations

Comment: Trigger `debugger;`? What are you trying to achieve by pausing? Different goals will require different approaches.

Comment: The argument to `setTimeout` is a function to call or a string to evaluate. Putting `console.log` there will call it immediately, not after the timeout.

Comment: Here's an option with more customization for when to "pause" and by how much: http://jsfiddle.net/R4jeL/

Answer (score 0):

As others have said there is no `pause` in JavaScript. Here is an example of what an asynchronous loop would look like;

```
(function() {
  var a = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,1];
  var i = 0;
  var length = a.length;

  function iteration() {
    if (i == length) return;

    console.log(a[i]);

    if(a[i] == 2){
      setTimeout(iteration, 1000);
    }else{
      setTimeout(iteration, 0);
    }

    i++;
  };

  iteration();
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly but you can emulate it as follows (you can test the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xSu5J/):

```
function myLoop(a) {
    function showElem(index) {
        if (index < a.length) {
            var nextWaitTime = (a[index] == 2) ? 1000 : 1; //1000: long period, 1: short period
            console.log(a[index]);
            setTimeout(function(){showElem(index+1)}, nextWaitTime);
        }
    }
    showElem(0);
}
myLoop([1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uqr49/

```
var a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3];

function pauseOnTwo(arr) {

    if (arr.length > 1) {
        var slice = arr.shift();
        if (slice === 2) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('found a two! ' + slice);
                pauseOnTwo(arr);
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            console.log('its not 2: ', slice);
            pauseOnTwo(arr);
        }

    } else {
        if (arr[0] === 2) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('found a two! ' + slice);
            });
        }
    }
}

pauseOnTwo(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below creates a function that takes 3 arguments, an array, the amount of time to pause (in milliseconds), and what to pause on. Inside the function it will create a private function that will be used to loop over the array. If the pauseOn value is encoutered a setTimeout is used to recall the loop function after the specified pauseTime

```
var arr = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,1];

function iterateArray(arr,pauseTime,pauseOn){
   var currentIndex=0;

   function loop(){    
      for(i=currentIndex;i<arr.length; i++){
         console.log(arr[i]);
         if(arr[i]==pauseOn){
            currentIndex = i+1;
            setTimeout(loop,pauseTime);
            return;
         }
      }
   }
   loop();
}
iterateArray(arr,3000,2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know why you want to acheive this, but if you wanna acheive this, you'll need a function that call itself :

```
function myLoop(index){ 
    index = index || 0;

    a = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,4,2,1]
    for (var i = index; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == 2){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(a[i]);
                myLoop(++i)
            }, 1000)
            break;
        }else{
            console.log(a[i]);
        }
    };    
}

myLoop()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUh3m/2/