# How to get rid of javascript maximum stack size

Tags: javascript

I need this code to iterate for about 10 seconds (or better indefinitely) without causing javascript maximum stack size. I have comented setInterval because it's causing the problem!

```
var myToggle = false;

function myFunc () {

    setTimeout(function () {

        if (myToggle) {
            console.log("red");
        }
        else {
            console.log("yellow");
        }

        myToggle = !myToggle;

    }, 500);
    // setInterval(myFunc, 10000);
}

myFunc();
```

Comment: You're question seems to be unclear !

Comment: There's no "iteration" going on here. Did you mean `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`? If so, then you won't have any stack size problems.

Comment: I have an implementation of something similar over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236754/js-for-loop-with-pauses/22236890#22236890

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm new to javascript and trying to learn it. I need to call the function indefinitely, perhaps by calling setInterval with the myFunc as a parameter and a delay. Or better call it with a callee or something, but without completely blocking the browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually a sign of bad design but the solution may be the following:

```
var myToggle = false;

function myFunc () {
    var startTime = new Date()/1;
    function wait () {
        if (myToggle) {
            console.log("red");
        } else {
            console.log("yellow");
        }
        myToggle = !myToggle;
        if (new Date() < startTime + (10*1000)) { // exit condition
            setTimeout(wait, 500);
        }
    }
    wait();
}

myFunc();
```

FYI: Infinite callbacks, among the other things, slowdown the browser and consume battery on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks Ilya, it works perfectly. Don't worry about browser slowdown, i'm not using this code, I'm just learning! I need to develop some thing else and these are just some bump ups I'm facing!

Answer (score 1):

Call setInterval instead. setTimeout will call the inner function once. setInterval will continue calling until you cancel.